# Shallow/deep-copy semantics in accessor/mutator

Tags: java

What's considered best practice when it comes to accessors/mutators and shallow/deep-copy? Or is this question specific to the situation at hand?

i.e.

```
public class Test {
    private final Point point = new Point(-32, 168);
    public void getPoint{
       return point
    }
}
```

My current thinking is to use deep-copy for anything mutable; therefore, if `Point` provided a setter, I would use deep-copy in `Test#getPoint`.

What's the status quo?

**[Edit]**

After `JB Nizet`'s answer, I found [this](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/OBJ05-J.+Defensively+copy+private+mutable+class+members+before+returning+their+references) great resource.

Comment: my current thinking is use 'deep-copy' only if you want a total separated object instead of a reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. Sometimes you want to return a reference to the object, and let the caller modify it. Sometimes you want to return a copy. In the case of a Point, a copy seems more appropriate, though.

Another way to protect the state of your class is to return an unmodifiable view of your field. This can be done by declaring the return type as an interface that only provides read-only methods, or, as in the Java collections api, by returning a wrapper object offering the same interface as the object but throwing exceptions when mutator methods are called.

Whatever the solution you choose, the key is to document what your method does.

Comment: +1 While I agree with most of your points, passing a reference of the object (read: internal state) to the caller is never a good idea IMHO, as it breaks encapsulation.

Comment: @Oliver Weiler - so you suggest creating a copy for any reference type that is to be passed to the caller?

Comment: @Oliver Weiler. If you have a factory object returning a singleton, you'll have to return the singleton reference. All objects don't have state, some objects have state but are immutable (String, Integer, etc.), and some stateful mutable objects are meant to be shared (Thread, Future, OutputStream).